# Values are not passing from HTML form into a PHP class

Tags: php, oop

> EDITED: Added checking stops into code.

keeping OOP design, what am I doing wrong?
The triangle sides are not passing into the classes properly.

I already tested the object with parameters inside the PHP file and it's working excellent. So it seems that the only culprit here is how I'm passing the params inside the classes.

Here is my **shape.php**:

```
    <?php
abstract class Shape{
    abstract protected function getArea();
    abstract protected function getPerimeter();
}

 class Triangle extends Shape{
    private $_sides = array();
    private $_perimeter = null;
     public $status = 0;

     function __construct($s0=0, $s1=0, $s2=0){
         $this->_sides[] = $s0;
         $this->_sides[] = $s1;
         $this->_sides[] = $s2;
         echo 'constructed<hr>';

         //calculate perimeter:
         $this->_perimeter = array_sum($this->_sides);
         echo 'calculated perimeter<hr>';
         $this->checkForm();
     }
     public function checkForm(){
         if (!empty($_POST['submit'])){
             $checkIt = $this->status = 1;
/*             echo 'status is <hr>'.$checkIt;*/

         }
         return $this->status;
     }
     public function proceed(){
         if ($this->status == 1){
             echo 'proceed func started<hr>';
             $this->_sides[0] = $_POST['s0'];
             $this->_sides[1] = $_POST['s1'];
             $this->_sides[2] = $_POST['s2'];

             echo 'Side 1: '.$this->_sides[0] = $_POST['s0'].'<hr>';
             echo 'Side 2: '.$this->_sides[1] = $_POST['s1'].'<hr>';
             echo 'Side 3: '.$this->_sides[2] = $_POST['s2'].'<hr>';


         }else{
             echo 'This didn\'t work as planned... :(';
         }
     }

    public function getArea(){

        return (sqrt(
            ($this->_perimeter/2) *
            (($this->_perimeter/2)- $this->_sides[0]) *
            (($this->_perimeter/2)- $this->_sides[1]) *
            (($this->_perimeter/2)- $this->_sides[2])
        ));
    }
    public function getPerimeter(){
        return $this->_perimeter;
    }
    }

/*$check = new Triangle(2, 2, 2);*/
$check = new Triangle();
echo $check->proceed();
echo 'status is: '.$check->status.'<hr>';

echo 'The '.get_parent_class($check).' is a '.get_class($check).'. It\'s Perimeter is: '.$check->getPerimeter().'M.<br>';
echo 'The '.get_parent_class($check).' also has an area of: '.$check->getArea().'M.<br>';
```

And this is my **index.php** file:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="boxy">
<form method="post" action="Shape.php">
<label for="s0">Side 1</label>
<input name="s0" type="number" placeholder="Side 0"><br>
<label for="s1">Side 2</label>
<input name="s1" type="number" placeholder="Side 1"><br>
<label for="s2">Side 3</label>
<input name="s2" type="number" placeholder="Side 2"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Run It.">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So where are you calling the `proceed()` method to populate the Triangle properties with the form values?

Comment: @MarkBaker - I changed the code and added 'echo' stop points, everything is passing right, how do I pass the newly $_sides from html into the new Triangle object?

Comment: @clusterBuddy It's better that you keep those properties and methods `private`, [http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39064701/1](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39064701/1)

Comment: So now you're setting the `_sides` property, but still not calling any calculation to set the  `_perimeter` value

Comment: Guys, The object and everything is working well, you can actually $check = new Triangle(2, 2, 2);
 and see that it responds well in the HTML, I just want to know how to pass the $_POST variables I got in the previous HTML page with form that I am trying pass into Triangle class.

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues with your code, such as:

- You're trying to set up triangle properties in the constructor but you're not passing any values. See this statement,

  ```
  $check = new Triangle();
  ```
- You didn't make use of `checkForm()` and `proceed()` method.

Though there are several solutions to this problem, one would be like this:

- Keep your constructor method empty, like this:

  ```
  function __construct(){}
  ```
- And change your `proceed()`, `getArea()` and `getPerimeter()` methods in the following way,

  ```
  private function proceed(){
      if ($this->status == 1){
          $this->_sides[0] = isset($_POST['s0']) ? $_POST['s0'] : 0;
          $this->_sides[1] = isset($_POST['s1']) ? $_POST['s1'] : 0;
          $this->_sides[2] = isset($_POST['s2']) ? $_POST['s2'] : 0;
      }else{
          echo 'This didn\'t work as planned... :(';
      }
  }

  public function getArea(){
      if($this->checkForm()){
          $this->proceed();
          return (sqrt(
              ($this->_perimeter/2) *
              (($this->_perimeter/2)- $this->_sides[0]) *
              (($this->_perimeter/2)- $this->_sides[1]) *
              (($this->_perimeter/2)- $this->_sides[2])
          ));
      }else{
          echo "Something went wrong. ";
      }
  }
  public function getPerimeter(){
      if($this->checkForm()){
          $this->proceed();
          return $this->_perimeter = array_sum($this->_sides);
      }else{
          echo "Something went wrong. ";
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: The object and everything is working well, you can actually $check = new Triangle(2, 2, 2);
 and see that it responds well in the HTML, I just want to know how to pass the $_POST variables I got in the previous HTML page with form that I am trying pass into Triangle class.

Comment: The object and everything is working well, you can actually $check = new Triangle(2, 2, 2);
 and see that it responds well in the HTML, I just want to know how to pass the $_POST variables I got in the previous HTML page with form that I am trying pass into Triangle class.

Comment: @clusterBuddy See the `getArea()` and `getPerimeter()` methods in my answer. These methods, in turn, call `proceed()` method, which actually gets all `$_POST` values and assigns them to `$_sides` property.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I actually found the error, I forgot to return the proceed() results.

Here it is amended and fully working:

```
abstract class Shape{
    abstract protected function getArea();
    abstract protected function getPerimeter();
}

 class Triangle extends Shape{
    private $_sides = array();
    private $_perimeter = null;
     public $status = 0;

     function __construct($s0=0, $s1=0, $s2=0){
         $this->_sides[] = $s0;
         $this->_sides[] = $s1;
         $this->_sides[] = $s2;
         echo 'constructed<hr>';

         //calculate perimeter:
         $this->_perimeter = array_sum($this->_sides);
         echo 'calculated perimeter<hr>';
         $this->checkForm();
     }
     public function checkForm(){
         if (!empty($_POST['submit'])){
             $checkIt = $this->status = 1;
/*             echo 'status is <hr>'.$checkIt;*/

         }
         return $this->status;
     }
     public function proceed(){
         if ($this->status == 1){
             echo 'proceed func started<hr>';
             $this->_sides[0] = $_POST['s0'];
             $this->_sides[1] = $_POST['s1'];
             $this->_sides[2] = $_POST['s2'];

             echo 'Side 1: '.$this->_sides[0] = $_POST['s0'].'<hr>';
             echo 'Side 2: '.$this->_sides[1] = $_POST['s1'].'<hr>';
             echo 'Side 3: '.$this->_sides[2] = $_POST['s2'].'<hr>';




         }else{
             echo 'This didn\'t work as planned... :(';
         }
         return $this->_sides;
     }

    public function getArea(){

        return (sqrt(
            ($this->_perimeter/2) *
            (($this->_perimeter/2)- $this->_sides[0]) *
            (($this->_perimeter/2)- $this->_sides[1]) *
            (($this->_perimeter/2)- $this->_sides[2])
        ));
    }
    public function getPerimeter(){
        return $this->_perimeter;
    }

    }

$check = new Triangle($_POST['s0'], $_POST['s1'], $_POST['s2']);
/*$check = new Triangle();*/
echo 'status is: '.$check->status.'<hr>';

echo 'The '.get_parent_class($check).' is a '.get_class($check).'. It\'s Perimeter is: '.$check->getPerimeter().'M.<br>';
echo 'The '.get_parent_class($check).' also has an area of: '.$check->getArea().'M.<br>';
```

Comment: It's not the case, you have access to your sides anywhere in the class. Don't know what was the issue though...